# net interactive notebook - show list as single grid

Tags: jupyter-notebook, .net-interactive

This was working for me on a different computer. It used to display everything in a single grid but now each item is expandable.

[image]

```
Formatter.Register<System.Boolean>(t => t ? @"<h1 style=""color:green;"">YES</h1>" : @"<h1 style=""color:red;"">NO</h1>", mimeType: HtmlFormatter.MimeType);

Console.WriteLine($"There are {tenantNames.Count} tenants.");
tenantNames.Display();    
tenantNames.Select( t => client.GetTenantSettings(t)).ToList().Display();
```

But now it seems to be showing me an expandable list instead of a single list

It was showing a single list with columns TenantName, MonitoringEnabled, DLQMonitoringEnabled before.

I can see on my old computer I had the ".Net Interactive Notebooks"
On the new computer I installed "Polyglot Notebooks"